# Radiobutton text above button shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a 2x2 grid with 4 buttons.
The label of each button should be above the actual button.

Is there such an option in R shiny?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Pretty radio buttons"),
  br(),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      prettyRadioButtons(
        inputId = "radio1",
        label = "Click me!",
        choices = c("Click me !", "Me !", "Or me !", 'Or me!')
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1"),
      br(),
      
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$res1 <- renderPrint(input$radio1)
  
  
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```